# Does the creation of a date object accept a parameter for a timezone?

Tags: swift

To my understanding `let date = Date()` would create a date object with my current timezone. I've seen that there are certain functions where I would use a date formatter to then convert it into UTC time and add the offset to that time and then convert back into a date object but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution? And if not is there any other way to get the current time in another timezone in a date object without using the data formatter, as I require the `calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)` to find the date of the week.

Comment: `Date()` is already UTC. SwiftUI's `.environment` for `TimeZone` automatically switches the UI to local time. If you want to inject a different time zone to show in the UI just inject the `.environment` for the `TimeZone` you want

Comment: @loremipsum Then is there a method to change the position that SwiftUI has of local time? A way to alter the position to specific coordinates then take the date at that position?

Comment: I don’t think so. You could make something with onChange. Something like onChange coordinates inject the new time zone. It would take a little bit of planning to come up with the right plan

Comment: I would assume that the coordinates of the current location is stored somewhere at least, is modifying this variable not possible in Swift UI.

Comment: Changing the “coordinates” of the device itself would likely cause a number of unknown issues. You would affect everything and this would definitely be outside of the scope of SwiftUI. So I would assume that you wouldn’t be allowed to do that. Like I said before the only way to change what SwiftUI displays is through .environment. SwiftUI is a UI framework modifying device settings would not be related to SwiftUI

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the very first line on [the documentation on Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date), you can read the following:

> A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone.

So your two options when you want to deal with a local date are the `DateTimeFormatter` and `Calendar`